# Apache Spark : Spring Transaction Not commiting

Tags: java, spring, transactions, apache-spark, jdbctemplate

I am using Spark and Spring JDBC Template class for commiting in DB. DB is MS SQL Server.
From Apache spark, mapToParition sends data in batches to DB via Springs batchUpdate in a transaction. The transaction gets completed but data doesn't get written to DB.

Does anybody know whats wrong here ?

```
          .mapToPartition(....) {
             call(..) {
               DefaultTransactionDefinition paramTransactionDefinition = new        
               DefaultTransactionDefinition();

               TransactionStatus status =  
               transactionManager.getTransaction(paramTransactionDefinition );
               .....
               ..... code for sql.......
               .....
               _jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(finalSql, jdbcArgs);
               transactionManager.commit(status);
             } // call ends
          }//mapToPartition ends
```

Here status.isCompleted() returns true.

This code works perfectly fine if I run in local[*] mode of apache spark, but when I run same code in Apache Spark's clustered/Distributed mode with 3 workers then it doesn't write any data to DB.

Comment: Could you clarify what is the scope of `transactionManager` and how it is created? What you want is that it (and all related spring instances) are instanciated and executed on the same JVM, i.e. be created and executed in the slaves, as opposed to being created in the master, wrapped in a closure and serialised to the slaves (which could lead to the issues you're facing). This depends on the structure of your code, though you could try encapsulating all the initialisation and `call` in a scala `object`. If done properly, this should lead to one initialisation per JVM, which is what you want.

Comment: `TransactionManager` is created once per application. Its type is `DataSourceTransactionManager`. As the application starts I inject the dataSources in `TransactionManager` through `Spring` and `broadcast` it in spark. When the actual hits comes I use it as in above code.

Comment: Just to add in the Question : `_jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(finalSql, jdbcArgs);` returns the correct count but still the data doesn't get written.

Comment: Also, I am making `defaultAutoCommit(false)` in connection before executing batchUpdate.

Comment: You want one `TransactionManager` per _JVM_, not per application. Remember a spark application is distributed across many JVM, and Spring does not let you serialize them, nor will coordinate synchronization of their state across the network.

Comment: @Svend : Thanks. I am creating `TransactionManager` inside `call(..)` method. I check it, if it is null then I create it. So Ideally it gets created on every JVM.